# Perl and SOAP WSDL. wsdl2perl doesn't work

Tags: perl, soap, wsdl

I have tried to generate perl classes for WSDL, but wsdl2perl.pl script doesn't generate most of classes. What's wrong?

xmethods.net WSDL Analyser returns no error and show AllegroWebApiService as service name

Script output [*HERE*](http://hash.su/7325)

WSDL [*HERE*](http://webapi.aukro.cz/uploader.php?wsdl)

Answer (score 3):

I don't have experience with wsdl2perl.pl, but CPAN reports that it was last updated in 2007.  I'm sorry I don't have a direct answer for you, but you might want to try a more modern SOAP library like [XML::Compile](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aCompile) or something battle-tested like [SOAP::Lite](https://metacpan.org/module/SOAP%3a%3aLite) to see if they fare better with the WSDL in question.